# How do I detach a screen session from a terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I know how to start a `screen`, and how to list different screens:

```
screen -ls
```

or to attach:

```
There are screens on:
        2477.pts-0.server1      (Detached)
        2522.pts-0.server1      (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.

$ screen -r 2477.pts-0.server1
```

But what is the key combination to detach from a screen session and keep it running?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd>. Note the lower case. The [[`screen` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/screen.1.html)] has a long list of these shortcuts under "DEFAULT KEY BINDINGS".

Comment: I think that you mean <kbd>Ctrl-A<kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> (lowercase).  The upper case (`D`) is 'powerdetach'.

Comment: yes, as @Arcege proposes, <Ctrl-A>  <d> detaches from current screen session. Which worked for me.  <Ctrl-A> <D> seemed to wait something else and received "detach aborted" message as soon as I pressed any other Key.  If <Ctrl-A> <D><D> pressed you're detached and logout from ssh.

Answer (score 75):

To list your sessions, run:

```
screen -list
```

---

You can run any command under  screen command like:

```
screen myscript.sh
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (release) and then <kbd>d</kbd> to detach the process/screen (so it'll continue to run).

---

To resume detached process, use:

```
screen -r
```

If you have multiple, then add the session number after that.

---

You can also re-attach to already `Attached` screen by `screen -x`. Useful to investigate why it's attached, share terminal with someone or to watch/check somebody what they're doing.

---

For more help, either run `man screen` or within the screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, release and then hit <kbd>?</kbd> to see more shortcuts.

See also:

- [How to execute a command in screen and detach?](https://superuser.com/questions/454907/how-to-execute-a-command-in-screen-and-detach)

Answer (score 12):

You'll probably see it listed like this in the screen man page:

```
^a - d
```

It's important the note the case of the letters as uppercase and lowercase will do different functions.

Answer (score 7):

> Create screen using this command:
> `screen -S testscreen`

> List the screen using this command: `screen -ls`

> Attache the screen using this command: `screen -r testscreen`

> Attache the multipurpose screen using this command (if already others are attached with the same screen): `screen -x testscreen`

> Detach the screen using this command: `screen -X detach` OR `Ctrl+a+d`

> Kill the screen using this command: `screen -XS testscreen kill`

> Terminate the attached screen using: `Ctrl+d`

Answer (score 5):

Some systems remove certain bindings by default.  So it is best to look at the online keybinding page: <kbd>Ctrl-a ?</kbd>.  You can also use the command prompt in `screen`: <kbd>Ctrl-a :detach</kbd>.  Myself, I generally remove the key bindings for 'detach' and 'powerdetach', except on remote systems.

Comment: "Some systems remove certain bindings by default" <- worth the upvote!