# How we can detach from screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I am new in linux. I used to work on windows(performance testing, load testing, smoke testing and so on ). I am doing a job which requires to perform some tests.

Comment: Ctrl+D terminates the whole screen. It disappears.

Comment: I think this post could help you :)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/124897/how-to-detach-a-screen-on-a-terminal

Comment: Yeah usefullllllll!

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+a` to enter command mode, then press `d`.  This will only detach your session, leaving any connections or programs you had open in there still running.  This sounds more like what you were after.

To view screen sessions, attached or no, type `screen -ls`

To re-attach to a session type `screen -r`: this will work if you have only one session out there.  Otherwise you'll have to specify to process id (pid) like so `screen -r 12345`.

There a LOT you can do with screen - this is just a thumbnail of what you can accomplish.

Bonus:  If you want a cheat sheet of useful screen command while you're in a screen session just hit `Ctrl+a` then type `:help`.

Welcome to the wonderful world of Linux, by the way.  Hope you enjoy your visit. :)